# Postfix + devocat + roundcube + WordPress - I can't receive emails and roundcube is showing nothing

Tags: apache2, email, postfix, dovecot, roundcube

I'm doing a migration for my client for his website based on WordPress - from hosting to VPS.
I am using apache2 for WordPress. I changed the DNS to the new IP (VPS) in the DNS control panel and WordPress is working good.

Now I want to configure e-mail on this server with panel to login to inbox etc. I am using [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/).

I installed `postfix`, `devocot` and `roundcube`. I created a user and I can send emails from the terminal with:

```
sendmail <delivery_email_address>
```

and these mails are received by my Gmail account.

But when I send email from my Gmail account to the same e-mail (VPS), I don't have anything. Roundcube is empty. I also checked `/var/mail/info` (info is the user), but also empty.

How can I troubleshoot this? What is not working properly here?

Additionally, I received emails from 'info@mail.mydomain.com', but my `hostname` variable in Ubuntu is 'domain.com' ('domain.com' is just an example). Is this a problem? Why?

Where I should search for the incoming mails? I guess Roundcube is loading mails from a specific file, and this file is empty, so is the inbox too?

General:

- `postfix`, `dovecot` services running
- Ubuntu  21.04
- Roundcube 1.4.8-complete

Comment: Nothing in this question deals with the OS. What has this got to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: It's not good forum to this question? I think it's ok, because it's administration problem on Ubuntu

Comment: No it is a problem with a number of apps that were never part of default Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you configured the MX record on the client’s domain to point to the VPS? If not, then the mail will go to wherever it went before, or it’ll return to your Gmail account after a day with a “No route to host” error.

Comment: Check your postfix log if anything is coming in. However, without in detail knowledge this is not answerable, it could simply be anything. Administration of an email server is a heavy task and imo beyond the specs of this website. Maybe try at serverfault.com, however, also there you should give more details.